# How to Duplicate Object and Randomize Specific Animation Feature?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, keyframes, pose-mode

so I have these characters that are doing the same movement, but I want them to blink at random times.

Is there a special way I can control the blinking to occur at different key frames without having to individually move each character?

The blinking is controlled with one single bone, so it should be easy to edit, but not sure how to do this across a large scale of duplicated objects?

Comment: Have you tried with the Nonlinear Aninmation editor?

Comment: what about using a driver with random value based on id of the bone?

Comment: well my blink bone already has a driver, so am I able to add additional drivers to it?? as for as nonlinear I haven't used that before

Comment: Maybe you should Show us your driver